# Pointers to pointers in hash Tables

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable

i don't quite understand why the following code does what it does.

```
void initializeTable()
{
 NodeT* (*hashTable) ;
 *hashTable=(NodeT*)malloc(30*sizeof(NodeT));
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
      (*hashTable)[i].info=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
       strcpy((*hashTable)[i].info,"a");
        cout<<(*hashTable)[i].info<<" ";

    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how hash Tables work. In the first version of my program I used something like `NodeT* hashTable[arraySize]` in order to create an array of pointers to `NodeT`, in order to do the chaining. After this I decided to try and allocate dinamycally memory for the array, so I tried to use the (I think) equivalent `NodeT* (*mockTable)`.

My question is the following: why do I have to use `(*hashTable)[i].info`, and not `(*hashTable)[i]->info` ? As far as i concerned, `hashTable` is a pointer which points to an array of pointers to `NodeT`, so this shouldn't happen. What am i getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You got the basic idea but it seem you miscount the pointers 
your hashTable is a pointer to pointer (**), and when you access it in the strcpy you actually get into the value of this double pointer the 1'st is with the array index [i] and the second is with the *hashTable which is when accessing a variable calling the Value inside it.
so if you define a duel pointer variable
StrutT **temp;
and you want to access a field inside it 
you can 
*temp[i].field
but in case you would only want to access at level of a single pointer (same **temp) you would need:
temp[i]->field
or 
*temp->field 
which both only "pop" the top most pointer